# Stub out a call to an array count with OCMock

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ocmock, xctest

I am trying to use a stub in OCMock (version 2) to catch a call to an array count and return the value I want.

I'm currently doing this:

```
id mockMutableArray = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSMutableArray class]];
[[mockMutableArray stub] andReturn:OCMOCK_VALUE(1)] count];
```

Which gives this error

```
Expected invocation with object return type. Did you mean to use andReturnValue: instead?
```

When I try this - using NSNumber as the argument to andReturnValue:

```
id mockMutableArray = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSMutableArray class]];
[[[mockMutableArray stub] andReturnValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] count];
```

I get the error message:

```
 Return value does not match method signature; signature declares 'I' but value is 'i'.
```

Don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Mocking an array is overkilling, just use a real one in your test.

Comment: Yep, kind of got stuck in a rut with that particular problem - I think I was trying to be too clever. I ended up creating a real array containing some mock objects. Much more useful. Thanks

Comment: Shall I put it as an answer, and we close the question?